# Помогите понять маленький кусок кода

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, тернарный-оператор

Помогите объяснить некоторые строки кода в функции
Интересует, что означают/делают строки maxSum = (maxSum < underDiagonal) ? underDiagonal : maxSum; и
maxSum = (maxSum < aboveDiagonal) ? aboveDiagonal : maxSum;
Что означает знак вопроса и что в целом происходит

```
    int maxsum(int** arr,int n)
{
    int maxSum = 1, underDiagonal = 0, aboveDiagonal = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
    {
        underDiagonal = 0;
        for (int j = 0, k = j; j < n - i; j++, k++)
        {
            underDiagonal += arr[j + i][k];
        }
        maxSum = (maxSum < underDiagonal) ? underDiagonal : maxSum;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        aboveDiagonal = 0;
        for (int j = 0, k = j; j < n - i; j++, k++)
        {
            aboveDiagonal += arr[j][k + i];
        }
        maxSum = (maxSum < aboveDiagonal) ? aboveDiagonal : maxSum;
        return maxSum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Выражение `a ? b : с` вычисляет логическое значение `a`, и если оно истинно - возвращает значение `b`, в противном случае - значение `c`.

По сути

```
maxSum = (maxSum < underDiagonal) ? underDiagonal : maxSum;
```

переписывается как

```
if (maxSum < underDiagonal) maxSum = underDiagonal;
```

(В соответствии с определением, конечно, как

```
if (maxSum < underDiagonal) maxSum = underDiagonal; else maxSum = maxSum;
```

но понятно, что ветвь `else` по сути не делает ничего и может быть выброшена.)